# I want to not repeat the name of the store and I want all the products that belong to it to appear together in the same box flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code-snippet

```dart
       var _productes = [];
      final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = 
      FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      getProducts() async {
      Query query = _firebaseFirestore.collection("CartOrder");

      var querySnapshot = await query.get();
     _productes.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
     }

       @override
       void initState() {
       getProducts();

        super.initState();
      }   
       for (var i = 0; i < _productes.length; i++) {
        _myDocument = (_productes[i]["cart"] as List<dynamic>)
           .map((m) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(m))
           .toList();
       }

             return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _myDocument!.length,
              itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, index) {
               for (var element in usersModel!.modelUsersList) {
              if (element.uid!.contains(_myDocument![index]["salleruid"])) {
                element = element;
              }
              }
              return usere(_myDocument![index], element);

             //  print(dty.contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid));
           });
         }
        

     usere(product, element) {
      return Row(
        children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Text(modelUsersList.userName.toString()),
              Text("${element.userName}"),
              Text("${product["title"]}"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
     }
```

I like to archive like the following image

[image]

I want to not repeat the name of the store and I want all the products that belong to it to appear together in the same box flutter

Thanks for the help
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you include your model class

Comment: I added some info

Comment: What will happen if you have 3 categories with 9 items

Comment: I don't want to repeat the store

Comment: https://shortest.link/2mLl the same shape